# Unable to write to matrix lines with parfor

Tags: matlab, parfor

How can I write into my result matrix lines using `parfor`?

Code sample:

```
xCount = 10;
yCount = 20;
area = xCount*yCount;
PP = nan(area,3);

parfor x = 1:10
    for y = 1:20
        id = y + (x-1)*yCount; % global PP line id.
        z = x^2+y*10; % my stuff to get Z.
        PP(id,:) = [x y z]; % write to PP line
    end
end
```

> The PARFOR loop cannot run due to the way variable 'PP' is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually says "Valid indices are restricted within PARFOR loops". The reason it says that it that MATLAB iterates through a `parfor` loop non-consecutive, meaning it can do iterations in semi-random order like `5 2 4 1 3`, as opposed to `1 2 3 4 5`. This means that in order to know where in `PP` MATLAB has to store your result, it wants to know before entering the parallel environment that no lines get called by different iterations, as to avoid conflicts when getting results back from the workers.

The solution will be to structure `PP` in such a way that it's known beforehand where the indices are stores, e.g. by creating a 2D array to use  before the loop to store stuff in:

```
xCount = 10;
yCount = 20;
area = xCount*yCount;
PP(xCount,yCount) = 0;
y=1:yCount;

parfor x = 1:xCount
    z = x^2+y.*10; % my stuff to get Z.
    PP(x,:) = z; % write to PP line
end
%// Go to the [x y z] format
PP = [repmat((1:yCount).',xCount,1),repmat((1:xCount).',yCount,1), PP(:)];
```

I'd personally not do the last line in this case, since it stores three doubles for each useful value (`z`), whilst in the 2D matrix that comes out of the loop it only stores 1 double which can be indexed by simply reading `PP(x,y)`. Thus it costs you 3 times the memory to store the same amount of useful data.

Comment: Instead of generating an array of indices I would say to just par-loop over `i=1:area` and then find the corresponding x,y values using `ind2sub([xCount, yCount], i)`. That way the assignment to `PP(i)` would be cleanly splice-able by Matlab.

Comment: Thanks! But I really disagree with Matlab team. In C# I'm able to do that. Matlab guys added some parfor extra protection layer that I think is just crap!! My id calculation was correct, and all ids would be unique. Really, this stinks!

Comment: @Pedro77 I'm not strong on the inner engine of MATLAB, but I guess something in the underbelly goes awry when there are two workers trying to simultaneously access the same element, hence it wants to know *beforehand* that all indices are unique. As for why it doesn't work like C#, simple, MATLAB ~= C#.

Comment: Extra crappy protection layer. Not intuitive. Bad documentation. Got an answer thanks to stackoverflow and you. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually is also doesn't work. Only Javier comment works.

Comment: Recheck it, Javier code works. For your solution I need to remap PP on your answer?

Comment: The changed version from @Adriaan should work; the only difference with mine is that this one keeps the inner loop, so the parfor runs on X and then each worker has a loop on Y while in mine the parfor runs on 1:area and there is no inner loop - each worker assigns 1 item. The assignment in my version needs to happen to `PP(i,:)`, though, that was a typo in my initial comment that did not show the 2nd dimension.

Comment: X and Y are also double, this was just a sample.